# How to Create Stripe PaymentIntent in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payment-intent

Message: Call to private method Stripe\ApiResource: :_validateParams() from context 'Stripe\PaymentIntent'

require_once('application/libraries/stripe/init.php');

```
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');

  \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
     'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
     'amount' => 1099,
     'currency' => 'usd',
     'customer' => '{{CUSTOMER_ID}}',
     'payment_method' => '{{CARD_ID}}',
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pre stripe documents, stripe use StripeClient() to set the apikey.

Replace

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');
```

with

```
\Stripe\StripeClient("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc");
```

[Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication)

Comment: i use Stripe Client () But some error occured
Message: Call to undefined function Stripe\StripeClient()

Comment: Make sure, you include the library properly ?